# Attributes in Zen cart

Tags: php, zen-cart

I was working with attributes in Zen cart and looking for the way to insert quantity for each product options, like I have a product called "Levis T-Shirt" and its having attributes like, "Color" & "Size", now i want to insert something like:

Levis T-shirt - Red Color - Large - Quantity 10
Levis T-shirt - Black Color - Medium - Quantity 15
Levis T-shirt - Blue Color - Large - Quantity 05

So how could I insert like this?

*Note: All this functionality is from admin at the time of saving products to DB*

Thanks,
In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this add-ons may help you.

http://www.zen-cart.com/index.php?main_page=product_contrib_info&products_id=310

Not tested.0